# Dynamic Class Choice Via ENV variable

Tags: php

I have a `Base` class that has some basic functionality and some helper methods. I want to extend from this class different methods, more than 10. So I would have `class Foo extends Base` and `class Bar extends Base` and so on. Now as far as calling this methods, the applications runs only 1 of these extensions depending on the environment, so for example on production `new Foo()` gets called and on development `new Bar()` gets called.

I have some basic functionality on these but I'm afraid it won't scale and/or it's not the best way to do things. I have an ENV variable called `CLASS_LOAD='bar'`. This is my code and how I'm doing it so far:

```
class Base {
    //
}

class Foo extends Base {
    //
}

class Bar extends Base {
    //
}

class ClassLoader {
    public static function init() {
        switch (getenv('CLASS_LOAD')) {
            case 'bar':
                return new Bar();
            case 'foo':
                return new Foo();
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

And the way I call this in my application is:

```
$class = ClassLoader::init();
```

This works fine for now I guess but I will have to keep updating the ClassLoader class every time I add a new extension of the Base class. And possibly in the future that switch-case statement will become unbearably large.

Can I be doing something else?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I have an idea that you should pass the class name to init function argument and by some methods create its instance and use this instance so that you would not require the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this approach that will no longer require switch statements and you don't have to panic anymore.

```
class ClassLoader{
     public static function init() {
      $class = getenv('CLASS_LOAD');
      if(class_exsists($class))
       return new $class;
      else
       throw new Exception("class not found");
  }
}
```

Now call it.